# How can I connect listview and audio player using audio_service and just audio

Tags: flutter, just-audio, audio-service

How can I connect my listview with audio player page using just_audio and audio_service.In audio service, all data is added to queue and play from first song. I want to start from index of item that is my click.How can I do that?Any example?

Answer (score 0):

You can also add single media item to audio handler of audio service. _audioHandler.addQueItem(mediaitem);  like this

Answer (score 0):

Use add Queue Item.

```
_audioHandler.addQueueItem(item);
```

Doc: https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service